# Axios download a file with support for pause and resume

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to find support for downloading a file with progress, pause, resume options.

The progress part i got covered, but i **can't find anything about pause / resume**.

Using Node/Electron enviorment.

```
const Fs = require('fs')
const Path = require('path')
const Axios = require('axios')

let startTime, endTime;

function start() {
    startTime = new Date();
};
function end() {
    endTime = new Date();
    var timeDiff = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
    console.log(timeDiff + " seconds");
}

async function downloadFile(url) {
    start();
    var received_bytes = 0;

    console.log('Connecting …')

    const { data, headers } = await Axios({
        url,
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'stream',
    })
    const totalLength = headers['content-length']

    const writer = Fs.createWriteStream(
        Path.resolve(__dirname, 'images', 'axios.jpg')
    )

    data.pipe(writer)

    data.on('data', (chunk) => {
        received_bytes += chunk.length;
        showProgress(received_bytes, totalLength);
    })

    data.on('error', (error) => {
        console.log('downloadError', error)
    })

    data.on('end', () => {
        end();
    })
}

function showProgress(received, total) {
    var percentage = (received * 100) / total;
    console.log(percentage + "% | " + received + " bytes out of " + total + " bytes.");
}

downloadFile('https://unsplash.com/photos/AaEQmoufHLk/download?force=true');
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no possibility to pause a request in the HTTP spec, so there is also no way axios could do this for you. If you really need pausing behavior, you can split the file over multiple requests and stop requests when you want to pause.

Comment: The user will decide when to pause/resume the download. Can you give a small example? Because i can't even think how to start doing it.

Comment: hey, have you ever solved this issue? i'm trying to do the same thing with partial requests